# What does Baymax's name mean?

Tags: marvel, big-hero-6

Since neither Wikipedia nor the Marvel Database seems to know, anyone here have any well-sourced idea where Baymax's name came from?

Comment: The Wikipedia entry indicates that, in his 1998 origin, he had two forms of `"Battle-Dragon" and "Action-Mecha"`. I suspect his name is a bit of a portmanteau of the two forms.

Comment: Always thought it sounded like [Betamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betamax)

Comment: @Stormblessed For the most part, I still refuse to believe it *isn't* Betamax.

Comment: In the original comic, [he just thought it was a cool name](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/5w1cah/comment/de70r36/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) apparently.

Comment: Reddit ain't a reliable source. Case in point, the original Baymax was a robot AI programmed with the kid's dead father's consciousness in a late 90s series, not the 'brother's engrams' in the 80s. That said, yeah, going through _Sunfire & Big Hero 6_ and (bizarrely) _Alpha Flight_, no, they never seem to mention where the name came from. Blehhh...

Answer (score -1):

The Chinese name for Baymax is [大](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7#Chinese)[白](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%99%BD#Chinese), pronounced *Dàbái* and meaning "Big" or "Great Whitey". Bái = BAY and "Big" = MAX. Put them together and reverse them, you get Baymax!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence that this is how the creators came up with the name?  You might as well claim it came from "BAY area Medical Assistant X;" without some proof this doesn't mean much.

Comment: Was it originally written in Chinese? Almost certainly not (everything else about the setting is _Japanese_) and 大白 is a calque _INTO Chinese_ of the original name (which is where that flip becomes necessary) and not in any way the source of the name.

Comment: @lly - The original comic was in English; https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sunfire_and_Big_Hero_Six_Vol_1_1. Baymax wasn't originally white.